# How to call a generic method on an CrudRepository from a extended typed CrudRepository?

Tags: generics, spring-data-jpa

I have below compilation error when I try to call (code below) a generic'd crudrepository interface's save method.

Should I be creating a interface between the the crudrepository and the IDateDescriptorRepository?
Am I missing a big point in crudrepositories (like I should use a single repo for all descriptor entities)? 
Am I missing something in the current code to make the save() call work?

Error:

```
DescriptorRepositoryHelper.java:32: error: no suitable method found for save(Descriptor)
    return descriptorRepoMap.get(descriptor.type).save(descriptor);
                                                 ^
method CrudRepository.<S#1>save(S#1) is not applicable
  (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: Descriptor
    upper bound(s): CAP#1)
method CrudRepository.<S#2>save(Iterable<S#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) S#2
    (argument mismatch; Descriptor cannot be converted to Iterable<S#2>))
where S#1,S#2 are type-variables:
 S#1 extends CAP#1 declared in method <S#1>save(S#1)
 S#2 extends CAP#1 declared in method <S#2>save(Iterable<S#2>)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
 CAP#1 extends Descriptor from capture of ? extends Descriptor
```

Code:
DescriptorRepositoryHelper

```
@Component
public class DescriptorRepositoryHelper {

 @Autowired
 private IDateDescriptorRepository dateDescriptorRepository;

 private Map<DescriptorTypes,CrudRepository<? extends Descriptor,Integer>> descriptorRepoMap = new HashMap<>();

 public DescriptorRepositoryHelper() {
    descriptorRepoMap.put(DescriptorTypes.DATE,dateDescriptorRepository);
 }

 Descriptor save(Descriptor descriptor) {
    return descriptorRepoMap.get(descriptor.type).save(descriptor);
 }
 ...
```

IDateDescriptorRepository

```
public interface IDateDescriptorRepository extends CrudRepository<DateDescriptor, Integer> {
}
```

DateDescriptor

```
@Entity
public class DateDescriptor extends Descriptor {
...
```

Comment: yeh check this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this source code for `CrudRepository` first.

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
     * entity instance completely.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @return the saved entity
     */
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    // Remainder omitted.
}
```

This will allow you to save any subtype of `T` and returns the same. In your case you can save any subtype of `Descriptor` including but not limited to `DateDescriptor`. Change your code like so in order to make it work.

```
public interface IDateDescriptorRepository extends CrudRepository<Descriptor, Integer> {

}

public class DescriptorRepositoryHelper {
    @Autowired
    private IDateDescriptorRepository dateDescriptorRepository;

    public DescriptorRepositoryHelper() {
    }

    Descriptor save(Descriptor descriptor) {
        return dateDescriptorRepository.save(descriptor);
    }
}
```

With that implementation, the use of `descriptorRepoMap` is no longer needed. Since the same repository can be used to save any subtype of `Descriptor` and you get exactly what you saved as return.

Especially for document-oriented data stores, it's not unusual to see subclasses persisted in the same repository as superclasses, and using S extends T as the parameter makes it much more flexible in supporting such usecases.